# How can I compile CoffeeScript from .NET?

Tags: javascript, .net, coffeescript

I want to write an HttpHandler that compiles CoffeeScript code on-the-fly and sends the resulting JavaScript code. I have tried MS [JScript][1] and IronJS without success. I don't want to use [Rhino][2] because the Java dependency would make it too difficult to distribute.

How can CoffeeScript be compiled from .NET?

Comment: This should be tagged `.net` as well, don't you think?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[**CoffeeScript-dotnet**](https://github.com/abolibibelot/coffeescript-dotnet#readme)

Command line tool for compiling CoffeeScript. Includes a file system watcher to automatically recompile CoffeeScripts when they change. Roughly equivalent to the coffee-script node package for linux / mac.

[**CoffeeSharp**](http://tomlokhorst.github.com/CoffeeSharp/)

Includes a command line tool similar to CoffeeScript-dotnet as well as a http handler that compiles CoffeeScripts when requested from an asp.net site.

[**SassAndCoffeeScript**](https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/SassAndCoffee)

Library for Asp.net mvc that compiles sass and coffeescript files on request. Also supports minification and combination.

[**Manually Compile With IronJS**](http://otac0n.com/blog/2011/06/29/CoffeeDemo-A-Simple-Demo-Of-IronJS-Using-CoffeeScript.aspx)

IronJS is a .NET javascript interpreter that can successfully load the CoffeeScript compiler and compile CoffeeScript.

**Manually Compile With Node.js**

Get the [node binaries](http://node-js.prcn.co.cc/) and add the bin directory to your path. Write a [node.js script to load the CoffeeScript compiler and your CoffeeScript files and save the compiled javascript](https://github.com/liammclennan/coffeescript-course/blob/master/util/l.js).

Comment: Also doesn't work correctly.  This snippet causes it to fail.  http://gist.github.com/566951

Comment: +1 for CoffeeSharp. It's available via Nuget, but bear in mind that the cmdline compiler was written in F#, so if you use CI you'll either need to deploy Fsharp core files to your CI server, or manually build a version that's standalone and use that instead.

Answer (score 32):

CoffeeScript is now fully supported by Chirpy:
http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

Comment: Note as of now, there is no syntax highlighting yet.

Answer (score 8):

You specifically said that you wanted to write a runtime compiler, so this may not be exactly what you are looking for, but if the main point is to have a way to generate the javascript result, the [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) is interesting.  It is a free extension for Visual Studio.NET 2010 and available in the Extension Manager. It gives Intellisense, syntax highlighting and compiles to JS as you write.  I am just getting started using it but looks promising.  Scott Hanselman talks about it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CoffeeScriptSassAndLESSSupportForVisualStudioAndASPNETWithTheMindscapeWebWorkbench.aspx). It also supports LESS and Sass.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to compile CoffeeScript from .NET using IKVM, jcoffeescript and Rhino. It was straightforward, except that the JCoffeeScriptCompiler constructor overload without parameters didn't work. It ran OK with a java.util.Collections.EMPTY_LIST as parameter.

This is how I did it:

1. Download IKVM, jcoffeescript and Rhino.
2. Run ikvmc against js.jar, creating js.dll.
3. Run ikvmc against the jcoffeescript jar.
4. Add a reference to the jcoffeescript dll in Visual Studio. More references may be needed, but you will be warned about those.
5. Run new org.jcoffeescript.JCoffeeScriptCompiler(java.util.Collections.EMPTY_LIST).compile() in your code.

The next step would be to create a build task and/or an HTTP handler.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the new [coffeescript-dotnet](https://github.com/abolibibelot/coffeescript-dotnet) project, which uses the [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) JavaScript implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Since the CoffeeScript compiler now runs on Internet Explorer, after a couple of recent tweaks, it should be good to go within other MS-flavors of JavaScript as well. Try including `extras/coffee-script.js` from the latest version, and you should be good to go with `CoffeeScript.compile(code)`.

Comment: I have tried that with the version that works in IE and it still crashes JScript and IronJS.

Comment: Crashes how? And feel free to pop into #coffeescript on FreeNode if you'd like to discuss it or ask for help.

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail. JScript gives an error, IronJS crashes the process. I got no response of #coffeescript.

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense ... Lexer.extensions is an empty array (unless you've extended CoffeeScript, which you haven't). I don't see why JScript wouldn't be able to declare the "_e" variable, especially when Internet Explorer has no trouble with it.

I'd be glad to investigate, if you can tell me how to get your setup setup (ha) on a Windows VM.

Comment: To track the error to a line number I used js beautifier. I think it introduced the error I described.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer, (I hope you find one), but maybe take a look at the following to see how it might be done.

- [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com) - JavaScript interpreter for .NET
- [Using IKVM to compile Rhino](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EmbeddingJSCS.aspx) would get rid of the Java runtime requirement.
- [jcoffeescript](http://github.com/yeungda/jcoffeescript). I haven't looked at jcoffeescript, but I think it depends on [JRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby) and Rhino.  You could possibly [IKVM.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKVM.NET) this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the bundled `extras/coffee-script.js` through Windows Based Script Host (or just wscript) and it didn't report any issues. I then added this line:

```
WScript.Echo(CoffeeScript.compile('a: 1'));
```

at the end of the file and run it through `wscript` again and it printed the resulting JavaScript correctly.

Are you using COM objects? Can you share some more of the code responsible for initialising the MScript object reference?

Comment: I tried this and it works fine with WScript, but the same script won't run with Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine. So the problem is I can't run it from code.

Comment: Wasn't `Microsoft.JScript.Vsa` deprecated?
Anything useful in `System.CodeDom.Compiler`?

Answer (score 1):

CoffeeScript in Visual Studio 2010

It's Chirpy's fork (chirpy is a tool for mashing, minifing, and validating javascript, stylesheet, and dotless files)

"OK, I think I got it working on my fork, based mostly on other peoples' work. Check it out:
http://chirpy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/Domenic/CoffeeScriptFixes"

from http://chirpy.codeplex.com/workitem/48

Answer (score 1):

IronJS now supports CoffeeScript and is generally faster than the other .NET JS engines:

I have a blog post about wiring the two together here:
http://otac0n.com/blog/2011/06/29/CoffeeDemo-A-Simple-Demo-Of-IronJS-Using-CoffeeScript.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My main editor is VS 2010 and I love the WorkBench extension. it's nice it auto compiles to js everytime you hit save on your .coffee file, also introduces you to SASS which I had read about but never got around.

They offer a pay version to that will autmaically shrink/minify your js and css files as well, since your.coffee and .scss are your source files anyway.

I'd encourage all VS users to go ahead and install this especially if you run VS 2010.

The only knock, and someone please correct me or enlighten me, is that with .coffee syntax it's not highlighted the way say html, js, c# code is. it might be because I am using a color scheme from http://studiostyl.es/ and for the record http://studiostyl.es/schemes/coffee- just shares the name coffee no special syntax highlight support for coffeescript that I am aware of. but no reason not to start using the workbench addin today!

Okay workbench website claims: syntax highlighting so again maybe it's the studiostyle.es i chose.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I came here to answer a very similar question: How do I get my CoffeeScript to compile using Visual Studio 2012 Express? Note that the free Express version does not allow any extensions so I could not continue to use the [Mindscape Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) extension that had served me well for quite some time.

It turns out to be very easy. Just use NuGet to install the [Jurassic-Coffee](http://nuget.org/packages/jurassic-coffee/) package and off you go.

One advantage of using this package over mindscape workbench is that you can reference your coffee directly from the script tags in the html. It minifies and caches the compiled JS so you only do work if the requested coffee file has changed.

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="home.coffee"></script>
</head>
```

The mindscape workbench allows you to bundle together different coffescript files which is very handy for modularising your coffeescript. You can also do this using Jurassic Coffee by utilising the `#= require` statement to include other coffee module files, for example:

```
#= require Classes\GridWrapper.coffee
class UsersGrid
  constructor:->
     @grid = new GridWrapper()
```

I think having the `#= require` staement in the coffee file is actually cleaner and clearer than the mindscape workbench approach, which kind of hides all this behind their interface so you forget easily what dependencies you have.

**Note**
There is one potential gotcha. The Nuget installer will put in an httphandler entry into your web.config that may not be compatible with IIS Express integrated managed pipeline mode.

You might therefore see the following error:

> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated
>   managed pipeline mode.

To fix this just remove the handler shown below.

```
<system.web>
  //other stuff

  <httpHandlers>
    <add type="JurassicCoffee.Web.JurassicCoffeeHttpHandler,JurassicCoffee" validate="false" path="*.coffee" verb="*" />
  </httpHandlers>

</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write a port of it to C#.  I have ported Jison to C# (which is the underlying project that makes CoffeeScript run).  I would think it may be a bit different, but both Jison parsers work the same.

I have not pull requested it back yet to Jison's main architecture, but will be doing so soon.

https://github.com/robertleeplummerjr

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shelling out to CScript you could shell out to Node.js ([here are self-contained Windows binaries](http://node-js.prcn.co.cc/))

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to compile the extras/`coffee-script.js` file, unmodified, to `jsc`, the [JScript.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET) compiler for .NET, and I got many errors. Here are the noteworthy ones:

- 'require' is a new reserved word and should not be used as an identifier
- 'ensure' is a new reserved word and should not be used as an identifier
- Objects of type 'Global Object' do not have such a member

Other errors were caused by the above said errors.

Comment: Did you compile wit `/fast-` to turn off all the JScript extensions?

Comment: @  Sean McMillan When I executed `jsc /fast- coffee-script.js` in `/extras`, I got too many warnings and An exe file was generated. I'm not sure if it was generated successfully. Anyway, I'll add a code to handle console input and see if I can get it running decently. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out jurassic-coffee, it is also a coffee-script compiler running the original compiler in jurassic.

It features sprocket style "#= require file.coffee" or "#= require `file.js`" wich can be used to keep .coffee files modular and combined right before compilation as well as embedding .js files.

It sports a HttpHandler with file watchers for .js and .coffee files that keeps track of what .coffee files needs to be re-compiled and pass through to the compiled *.js files for the rest.

jurassic-coffee is also available as a Nuget package

https://github.com/creamdog/JurassicCoffee

Answer (score 0):

I've done an HttpHandler that uses Windows Script Host behind the scenes: https://github.com/duncansmart/LessCoffee and works great (it also compiles [*.less](http://lesscss.org/) files).

It's on NuGet: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/LessCoffee

It's based on this simple wrapper: https://github.com/duncansmart/coffeescript-windows

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an inteructive shell using v8.

https://github.com/mattn/coffee-script-v8

This work as single executable file. (Don't use external files)
It can't use require(). But enough to learn coffeescript.